# How to retrieve data from many to many relationship with Lift

Tags: lift

Let say I have 3 tables: Book, Author and BookAuthor.

```
Book has id, title
Author has id, name
BookAuthor has id, book_id, author_id
```

I want to find all authors of a book. Can anyone guide me how to do this with Lifts mapper syntax?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Book extends LongKeyedMapper[Book]
                               with IdPK
                               with ManyToMany { 
    def getSingleton = Book
    object title extends MappedString(this, 255)
    object authors extends MappedManyToMany( 
        BookAuthors, BookAuthors.book, BookAuthors.author, Author) 
}

object Book extends Book with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Book]

class Author extends LongKeyedMapper[Author]
                                 with CreatedUpdated with IdPK
                                 with ManyToMany { 
    def getSingleton = Author
    object firstName extends MappedString(this, 255)
    object lastName extends MappedText(this)
    object email extends MappedEmail(this, 150)
    object books extends MappedManyToMany( BookAuthors, 
             BookAuthors.author,     BookAuthors.book, Book)

}

object Author extends Author with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Author]

val warandpeace = Book.create.title("War and Peace").saveMe
val fred =  Author.create.firstName("Fred").saveMe
fred.books += warandpeace
fred.saveMe
val bob =  Author.create.firstName("Bob").saveMe
bob.books += warandpeace
bob.saveMe

// then to find all the authors of the book:
val authors = warandpeace.authors
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mapper for the book:

```
class Book extends LongKeyedMapper[Book] with IdPk with OneToMany[Long, Book] {
  def getSingleton = Book
  object title extends MappedString(this, 200)
  object BookAuthor extends MappedOneToMany(BookAuthor, BookAuthor.id)
}
object Book extends Book with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Book]
```

The trait IdPk will take care of the id of Book. Then for BookAuthor:

```
class BookAuthor extends LongKeyedMapper[BookAuthor] with IdPk with OneToOne[Long, BookAuthor] {
  def getSingleton = BookAuthor
  object Author extends MappedOneToOne(Author, Author.id)
}
object BookAuthor extends BookAuthor with LongKeyedMetaMapper[BookAuthor]
```

Then for Author, a simple mapper:

```
class Author extends LongKeyedMapper[Author] with IdPk {
  def getSingleton = Author
  object name extends MappedString(this, 200)
}
object Author extends Author with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Author]
```

Then the call to find all authors of a book (here `myBook` ):

```
myBook.BookAuthor.map(x => x.Author.name)
```

If you want to make more complicated join requests without having to filter everything in Scala, you can always use [DB](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.db.DB) and you can always find more info about mapper [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper).

Comment: You use OneToMany on both entities, why? I have a ManyToMany relationship and I think I set this up right. Question is only how to get all authors for a book with that intermediate table BookAuthor in between. BTW, what is class Concert?

Comment: Hi, I corrected my typo about "concert", bad copy-paste. However, for more details you must see the documentation of mapper as I specified in my post. The important things I wanted to highlight are that you can do `myBook.BookAuthor` and get a List of `BookAuthor`.

Comment: It seems like this paragraph can interest you: http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper#manytomany